# Dropdown using bootstrap select gives blank dropdown

Tags: php, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have been looking at other related questions but I was unable to solve my query. I am using `PDO:postgresql-php` to retrieve values from database and display options in the `dropdown` using select options. The code was working till I used `bootstrap-selectpicker` and since then I am unable to see values in dropdown. You can see the code below:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-info">
           <option hidden><h4>Please select the lake</h4></option>
           <?php
                 $sql=$conn->prepare("select colname from public.table where id< 5"); 
        $sql->execute();
        if (!$sql) {     die('Could not connect: '); }
        while ($row = $sql->fetch()){
            echo '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($row['colname']).'">'.htmlspecialchars($row['colname']).'</option>';
        }

   ?>
     </select>  
    <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.selectpicker').selectpicker(
            style: 'btn-info',
            size: 4
            );

          });
    </script>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct Bootstrap Select is achieved as follows:

```
<select class="form-control">
```

As taken from: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The methid you described works and is easier than what I was doing.I want to see this as a button rather than a search text in a form. Is it possible to show it as a button which when I click shall open a dropdown list?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, do you mean you want to click on a button then it have a select box?

Comment: I styled it like a box. Just solved the above as I wanted to. :) 
Thanks alot

Comment: No problem, choose an answer so it can be marked as solved for other users :)